# How to override texture color in opengl?

Tags: opengl, texture2d, text-rendering

I am working on engine (http://b2dengine.com/) to implement my game idea, which is already in progress. Now for quite a while I am stuck with this problem with text rendering.

I have texture atlas that contains all supported/needed characters in a single png image. Character mapping is defined by `Font` class. 
Everything works fine, characters are rendered correctly and accurately. Thing is that I also need ability to change color of the text. 
This sounds and I bet it is simple but I cant make it work.

I am using this gl blend function to get desired effect.

```
GL.instance.glBlendFunc(GL.instance.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.instance.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

In most cases it works, well as long as the color is somewhat dark. But when its set to white, I can see artifacts. I can provider screenshot if needed.
Also for this to work, "text" in texture must be white.

I am using opengl 1.1 ( yes I know its old, but I am just not ready for shaders ).

So in short, my question is: how to render a texture and completely replace the color? Keeping only alpha channel. 
E.g. if its black and 80% transparent in png, when I render I want it green at 80% transparency on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this will work, though these are some anciently deprecated functions and I don't remember too much about them anymore.

With your texture unit active which has the text texture, try setting these options:

```
glTexEnv(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnv(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnv(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_RGB, GL_PRIMARY_COLOR);
glTexEnv(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_ALPHA, GL_TEXTURE);
```

I believe this will replace the RGB of your fragment with the incoming fragment color (glColor), and completely ignore the RGB channel of the texture. Having said this, it would be a lot better if you just uploaded an alpha channel texture to begin with.

Make sure to check for errors, and if it doesn't work, you can see if I've grabbed something incorrectly from here: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml

Comment: I don't know what version of GL the author of this post uses but glTexEnv is deprecated by now.Read this:http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes:_Deprecated#glTexEnvi .And especially pay attention on this line:" Also keep in mind that glTexEnvi has no effect when a fragment shader is bound."

Comment: @MichaelIV, I agree that it is deprecated, but OP clearly says that he is using very old opengl (1.1)

Comment: Ah yeah , not I see it . Too bad for him ;)

Comment: It did't work, but thanks for the idea with alpha only image. I am pretty new to opengl, that why I took old version. As it seems much easier to learn, at first I want to get a good idea on how things work. With the work I've done so far, opengl part is relatively small. So porting it to OpenGL SE 2 wont be that hard :)

Comment: *I am pretty new to opengl, that why I took old version.* I'm sure you've heard it before, but believe me that this is a pretty bad idea. Shaders are so much more intuitive than these stupid old texture combiner functions, what you want to do can easily be achieved in a single easy to understand line of one shader. Trust me that you will be much better served by just jumping into modern OpenGL with both feet than learning these old methods. Remember, they were deprecated for a reason. @FDIM

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I think Ill do that when I release the game. Because now, basically only this small thing with text stands in my way. If I am to refactor, I would delay game development - which is already delayed more than enough.

Comment: @FDIM, understood, sorry that my solution didn't work. I'm sure that what you're looking for can be found on that glTexEnv page I linked, though it's some pretty hairy documentation so you might have to experiment with it for a while.